# How do I set up a simple dockerized RabbitMQ cluster?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, ubuntu-16.04

I've been doing a bit of reading up about setting up a dockerized RabbitMQ cluster and google turns up all sorts of results for doing so on the same machine.

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ cluster across multiple machines.

I have three machines with the names `dockerswarmmodemaster1`, `dockerswarmmodemaster2` and `dockerswarmmodemaster3`

On the first machine (dockerswarmmodemaster1), I issue the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 4369:4369 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15671:15671 -p 15672:15672 \
    -p 25672:25672 --hostname dockerswarmmodemaster1 --name roger_rabbit \
    -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

Now this starts up a rabbitMQ just fine, and I can go to the admin page on 15672 and see that it is working as expected.

I then SSH to my second machine (dockerswarmmodemaster2) and this is the bit I am stuck on. I have been trying variations on the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 4369:4369 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15671:15671  \
    -p 15672:15672 -p 25672:25672 --name jessica_rabbit -e CLUSTERED=true \
    -e CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit@dockerswarmmodemaster1 \
    -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' \
    rabbitmq:3-management
```

No matter what I try, the web page on both RabbitMQ machines says that there is no cluster under the 'cluster links' section. I haven't tried involving the third machine yet.

So - some more info:

1. The machine names are resolvable by DNS.
2. I have tried using the --net=host switch in the docker run command on both machines; no change.
3. I am not using docker swarm or swarm mode.
4. I do not have docker compose installed. I'd prefer not to use it if possible.

Is there any way of doing this from the docker run command or will I have to download the rabbit admin cli and manually join to the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/aweber/rabbitmq-autocluster to create a RabbitMQ docker cluster.

The plugin uses `etcd2` or `consul` as service discovery, in this way you don't need to use the `rabbitmqctl` command line.

I used it with docker swarm, but it is not necessary.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9KH_FWJ2ek) is the result

Answer (score 2):

The official container seems to not support environment variables `CLUSTERED` and `CLUSTER_WITH`. It supports only a list variables that are specified in [RabbitMQ Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).
According to official [Clustering Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html), one of possible solutions is via configuration file. Thus, you can just provide your own configuration to the container.
Modified default configuration in your case will look like:

```
[ 
  { rabbit, [ 
    { loopback_users, [ ] }, 
    { cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@dockerswarmmodemaster1'], disc }} 
  ]} 
].
```

Save this snippet to, for example, `/home/user/rmq/rabbitmq.config`. 
Hint: If you want to see node in management console, you need to add another file `/home/user/rmq/enabled_plugins` with only string

```
[rabbitmq_management].
```

after that, your command will look like

```
docker run -d -p 4369:4369 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15671:15671  \
-p 15672:15672 -p 25672:25672 --name jessica_rabbit \
-v /home/user/rmq:/etc/rabbmitmq \
-e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' \
rabbitmq:3-management
```

PS You may also need to consider setting environment variable RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a cluster, all rabbitmq nodes that are to form up a cluster must be accessible (each one by others) by node name (hostname).
You need to specify a hostname for each docker container with `--hostname` option and to add /etc/host entries for all the other containers, this you can do with `--add-host` option or by manually editing /etc/hosts file.
So, here is the example for a 3 rabbitmq nodes cluster with docker containers (rabbitmq:3-management image).

First, create a network so that you can assign IPs: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet1`. We are going to have the following:

- 3 docker containers named rab1con, rab2con and rab3con
- IPs respectively will be 172.18.0.11 , -12 and -13
- each of them will have the host name respectively rab1, rab2 and rab3
- all of them must share the same erlang cookie

Spin up the first one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.11 --hostname rab1 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab1con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

second one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.12 --hostname rab2 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab2con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

last one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.13 --hostname rab3 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --name rab3con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

Then, in container rab2con, do

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rab1
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

and the same in rab3con and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness (last answer 8 years ago), here is a possible solution in **2024** to use the [bitnami/rabbitmq](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/rabbitmq) Docker image to easily create a full **RabbitMQ cluster with a Docker compose file**.

From the [README](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/rabbitmq/README.md#setting-up-a-cluster):

> ```
> services:
>   stats:
>     image: bitnami/rabbitmq
>     environment:
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_TYPE=stats
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@stats
>       - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=s3cr3tc00ki3
>     ports:
>       - '15672:15672'
>     volumes:
>       - 'rabbitmqstats_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia'
>
>   queue-disc1:
>     image: bitnami/rabbitmq
>     environment:
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_TYPE=queue-disc
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@queue-disc1
>       - RABBITMQ_CLUSTER_NODE_NAME=rabbit@stats
>       - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=s3cr3tc00ki3
>     volumes:
>       - 'rabbitmqdisc1_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia'
>
>  queue-ram1:
>     image: bitnami/rabbitmq
>     environment:
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_TYPE=queue-ram
>       - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@queue-ram1
>       - RABBITMQ_CLUSTER_NODE_NAME=rabbit@stats
>       - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=s3cr3tc00ki3
>     volumes:
>       - 'rabbitmqram1_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia'
>
> volumes:
>   rabbitmqstats_data:
>     driver: local
>   rabbitmqdisc1_data:
>     driver: local
>   rabbitmqram1_data:
>     driver: local
> ```