# How to setup a RabbitMQ cluster on Docker Cloud?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

**I am trying to setup a RabbitMQ cluster via DockerCloud**, and sort of lost.

There are plenty of tutorials out there, but I cannot figure out how Docker Cloud is creating the clusters so I can deploy and connect two running RabbitMQ services?

**What I have so far:**

- Create two nodes via Docker Cloud (AWS)
- Create a cluster of those two nodes
- I deployed a RabbitMQ container on one of the two nodes

Now I don't know where to go from there.

**Questions I have:**

> - How do I deploy two instances of RabbitMQ and link them together?
> - If they are linked, how is Docker Cloud managing it? Or do I have to do this over the admin GUI?

Any guidance or pointing me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here I answered to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/41307591/1437693. In your case, make sure you set flag `RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a simple dockerized RabbitMQ cluster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302117/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-dockerized-rabbitmq-cluster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a guide on how to set it up on Docker Cloud, here an explanation:

1. Create two (or more) nodes via the GUI on Docker Cloud with your preferred hosting provider (I chose AWS)
2. Create a Node Cluster via the GUI on Docker Cloud and choose you just created nodes
3. I used a pre-configured image on [GitHub](https://github.com/harbur/docker-rabbitmq-cluster/blob/master/rabbitmq-cluster).

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
MAINTAINER Dimitris Kapanidis dimitris.kapanidis@harbur.io

COPY rabbitmq-cluster /usr/local/bin/
COPY pre-entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 5672 15672 25672 4369 9100 9101 9102 9103 9104 9105
ENTRYPOINT ["/pre-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["rabbitmq-cluster"]
```

The important part (especially for Docker Cloud) is the **rabbitmq-cluster file**:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=`hostname`
RABBITMQ_NODENAME=${RABBITMQ_NODENAME:-rabbit}

if [ -z "$CLUSTER_WITH" -o "$CLUSTER_WITH" = "$hostname" ]; then
  echo "Running as single server"
  rabbitmq-server
else
  echo "Running as clustered server"
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached
  rabbitmqctl stop_app

  echo "Joining cluster $CLUSTER_WITH"
  rabbitmqctl join_cluster ${ENABLE_RAM:+--ram} $RABBITMQ_NODENAME@$CLUSTER_WITH

  rabbitmqctl start_app

  # Tail to keep the a foreground process active..
  tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/*
fi
```

In Docker Cloud, create a new service and search for `harbur/rabbitmq-cluster`. When deploying the image, select "deploy on every node", and use tags to identify your cluster nodes.

In the environment variables, enter:
CLUSTER_WITH: rabbitmq-cluster-1 (the name of your first instance)
ERLANG_COOKIE: abcdefg

> The rabbitmq-cluster script gets executed on every node
>   (rabbit-mq-cluster-1, rabbit-mq-cluster-2 etc.), so the environment
>   variable makes sure just to join those hosts which are not the first.
>   This makes sure that you can scale via the Docker Cloud, and new nodes
>   automatically gets clustered with your first node.